# DomDocument fetch h1 tag

Tags: php, regex, domdocument, scrape

I have very very big html page/data. I need to fetch data under h1 tag.
so what I have seen on various example is DOMDOCUMENT is basically used for parsing xml.
but if i have html data, very meshu, and I want to fetch text under `<h1></h1>` tag then what will be code.

If there are number of `<h1>` tags

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

@$doc->loadHTML($this->siteHtmlData);

$aElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("h1")
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are having a problem with. The code above should populate `$aElements` with a `DOMNodeList` containing all the `<h1>` tags - what is not working?

Comment: above code showing me output only :
<pre>DOMNodeList Object
(
) not the text under h1 tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop it to get the value:

```
foreach ($aElementsas as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```